# Does chaining jQuery selectors have any negative effects?

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-selectors, chaining

Are there any negative implications to chaining jQuery API calls on a selector?
Negative implications dealing with performance, design, susceptibility to memory leaks are what I'm particularly interested in.

So, would chaining a statement such as this:

```
$('.myElement').css('color','green')
               .attr('title','My Element')
               .click(function(){ console.log('clicked') });
```

Leave the application open to any of the aforementioned negative implications?

I personally don't have any problems with chaining jQuery expressions at all, but I've seen a lot of people bash chaining and I want to know if there is any concrete benefits of avoiding it, or if it's just a matter of readability and personal style.

Comment: Besides design, which i cannot see how it could be affected by syntax, the other negative effects you ask about seem only to be possible as a particular interpreter implementation weakness.

Comment: "a lot of people bash chaining" => references?

Comment: In my work, and I've seen examples in here recently too. I'll see if I can dig them up, one for sure was on a recent bounty question where the answerer told the questioner to "quit chaining, that's how hipsters code and is probably the cause of your problems you're experiencing" :)

Comment: Chaining is one of JQuery's main strong points... if you use JQuery, I can't see why you should not chain. It's more JQuery bashing I think, which has valid points.

Comment: The problem isn't with jQuery's chaining. It's with jQuery itself, it's [flawed](https://gist.github.com/1417030) and incurs a performance penalty that's an order of magnitude on average.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chaining is actually better than doing this:

```
$('.myElement').css('color','green')
$('.myElement').attr('title','My Element')
$('.myElement').click(function(){ console.log('clicked') });
```

Since doing so would make jquery 'jump into the pool' looking for my element 3 times, while if you chain your orders it will just look in the pool once (notice the pool is the DOM :)

Comment: Yes, chaining is better than your example, but you're implying that by not chaining, you must do redundant DOM selection, which isn't the case.

Answer (score 2):

Chaining is just invoking a method on a returned object. There's nothing inherently good or bad about that. Some like it, some don't.

---

With respect to memory leaks, jQuery does keep a cached set of jQuery objects when you've done DOM traversal. This doesn't really have much to do with chaining, since a referenced jQuery object will do the same thing, but I suppose it could cause a leak if you keep a permanent reference to the object.

---

For example, if you do this...

```
var jq_obj = $('.my_class').parents('.another_class');
```

...the jQuery object now has a reference to ancestors of the `".my_class"` elements that have the `".another_class"` class.

The thing is that you can then do this...

```
jq_obj.end();
```

...and you now have a reference to the original `".my_class"` elements selected. This means that the original references were maintained.

---

So if after calling `.parents()`, if you stopped there *(didn't call `.end()`)*, and if you kept a global reference to that `jq_obj` object, you'd now have an implicit reference to all the `".my_class"` elements in addition to the `".another_class"` elements.

As such, if any of the original `".my_class"` elements are removed from the DOM, they can't be GC'd because of that reference.

---

Here's an example...

http://jsfiddle.net/aUEFc/

```
   // select "my_class" then traverse to a parent
var jq_obj = $('.my_class').parents('.another_class');

   // remove "my_class" elements from the DOM
$('.my_class').remove();

   // see if we still have a reference to "my_class" elements
var len = jq_obj.prevObject.filter('.my_class').length;
```

The `len` variable will be the original number of `".my_class"` elements that were selected  even though the `".my_class"` elements were removed.

This is the case even though our `jq_obj` object is referencing the `".another_class"` elements. The reason is that the `.prevObject` property references the jQuery object that did the original DOM selection, so the nodes are never released as long as `jq_obj` survives.